# Does attachment and love coexist?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, love, non-attachment

Plenty of slokas in Geetha says that attachment is a bad thing and one should leave it.

My doubt is "Can both love and attachment coexist?"

Let us consider Yashoda as well as gopi's, I allegedly know that Yashoda and gopi's cry for Krishna's (physical body) presence. It shows that they are physically attached to Krishna. Is it attachment or love?

Let us consider Vasista, he didn't cry even though his sons die in front of his eyes because he has no attachment but only loves if I'm true.

Most people say that Yashoda and gopi have love for Krishna. If it is true, then attachment and love can coexist. Is it true? If they can coexist, then why Geetha says attachment is a bad thing?

Comment: Moha is bad and called attachment. But love is not "Moha".

Comment: Does Yashoda and gopi's have such moha on Krishna? @TheDestroyer

Comment: Yes attachment causes suffering. Love causes happiness. If at all you are attached to something, then attach yourself to God. Because God is Immortal and Eternal. By being attached to God, all your other attachments disappear. That is why Yashoda and Gopikas are exemplified. Because by focussing their attachment to God, although they underwent suffering due to the physical attachment, eventually they attained Perfection, for the Lord liberates His devotees. Sri Ramakrishna often said 'Cry for the Divine like a child for its mother, then God will come to you !' (paraphrased) All the best!

Comment: Attachment/Love/Kama for Krishna is correct.

Answer (score 4):

This might help:

> Q: What is the difference between love and attachment?
>
> Sri Sri:
> Attachment is that which gives you pain. Love is that without which
> you cannot live. If love becomes attachment, then the same love which
> was giving you joy, starts to inflict pain. Attachment is when you
> want something in return. If you love and don't want anything in
> return, then that love doesn't turn into attachment.

Excerpt from a Q&A with Sri Sri Ravi Shankar: https://plus.google.com/+SriSriRaviShankar/posts/DJmmZLpX5vy

Comment: It says that both can coexist, bit this question claims that those who possesses attachment cannot really love.

https://www.quora.com/Bhagwad-Gita-says-He-who-has-no-attachments-can-really-love-others-Can-anyone-please-clarify-difference-between-love-and-attachment

Comment: @hanugm: I do not agree to the notion that if you are attached you cannot love. In fact, attachment is born out of love. The only issue is that attachment causes pain and love does not. Otherwise, we would not be asking this question if attachment was not causing pain and was all good. :)

In my mind, love+ignorance = attachment. Hence, we need to deal with the ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

Attachment is poison disguised as love. In attachment you care for others only for your benefit. That's why you hear things like "I did so many things for so and so person and see what I got back in return". Where was love here if you expecting someone in return? It's called hidden business.

Love is a very high word. Not everyone can love. Most of the relationships which you see around you of husband-wife, parents-children are that of attachment not of love. Also love is not about saying lovely things to others. It also includes saying harsh words for betterment of others. Guru-shishya is one of the examples of love.

Love is about giving, giving and giving without nothing in return. You just want the best for other person with nothing in return.

No love and attachment can't coexist.

The example of Gopi and Yashoda Mata which you mentioned is definitely of love. What's better example of love better than Gopis. Their crying for physical presence is just Lila. Inwardly they don't care if Krishna is infront of their eyes or not. If you read Bhagvatam, you realise this truth.

Please watch this video, because this is very important question https://youtu.be/qiUx6l1KxrQ